# find in which sublist of a list are any value of a list in python

Tags: python

I want to return a NumPy array of Element IDs with at least one Node being in the interesting Nodes list.

I have:

- A list of interesting Nodes, `Interesting_Nodes`.
  The size is ~300,000 items.
- A list of sublists which represent Node forming an Element, `Nodes`.
  The size is ~1,000,000 lists of ~20 values.

  `Nodes[i]` contain the 20 Nodes creating `Elements[i]`. Which is an integer ID.
- A list of Elements, `Elements`.
  The size is ~1,000,000 items.

Here is an example of these lists.

```
import numpy as np
Interesting_Nodes=[1,2,10,40,400,1000]
Elements=[1,2,3]
Nodes=[[1,20,25],[30,400,35],[500,501,502]]
```

In this case the function will return `[1,2]` because `Elements[0]` have the Node 1 in the `Interesting_Nodes` list and `Elements[1]` contains the Node 400 which is also in the `Interesting_Nodes` list

I wrote this it seems to work but is very slow. Is there a way to perform this faster?

```
def recuperation_liste_element_dans_domaine_interet(Interesting_Nodes,Elements,Nodes):
    Liste_elements=list([])
    for n in Interesting_Nodes:
        id=np.where(Nodes==n)
        Liste_elements=Liste_elements+list(Elements[id[0]])
    nbrListe = list(set(Liste_elements)) # remove all the element duplication
    return np.array(nbrListe)
```

Another way to perform that I think could be: (be still too slow)

```
def recuperation_liste_element_dans_domaine_interet(Interesting_Nodes,Elements,Nodes):
    Liste_elements=[0]*len(Elements)
    compteur=0
    j=0
    for n in Nodes:
        if any(i in Interesting_Nodes for i in n):
            Liste_elements[compteur]=Elements[j]
            compteur=compteur+1
        j=j+1
    Liste_elements=Liste_elements[:compteur]  
    return np.array(Liste_elements)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `Elements` is always a list of continuous indices from zero to the length of `Nodes` minus one and thus strictly not needed.

As a general guideline, explicit loops tend to be slow and also hard to read (and non-Pythonic).

To solve your problem efficiently, use data structures (namely [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)):

```
import numpy as np

# Suppose you start with these lists
u = [1,2,10,40,400,1000]
n = [[1,20,25],[30,400,35],[500,501,502]]

# Convert them into sets
u = set(u)
n = [set(x) for x in n]

#  An individual bit is true if the corresponding list is "interesting"
idx = [bool(a.intersection(u)) for a in n]

# Perhaps convert to integer indices if you wish
np.where(idx)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I figured out myself that set is much more powerful to do what I expected 1 hour ago ;) But not as "clean" as you write. I think it would do the job perfectly ! Thanks again !

Comment: By the way in fact i need Elements because it is not a continuous list. It coub be [10,1000,300]. But with idx I suppose I can juste write Elements[idx] to have my answer.

Comment: Did you see an improvement in your "very slow" execution time? What kind of improvement did you see?

Comment: a HUGE improvement !!! With the previous version, with the "utltimate" amount of data, i never manage to reach the end. With the new version, the code finish in few minutes. Thank you again @Juho